# Transforming a dataframe by creating a new column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with results of t-test in long format and would like to transform it so that the information of p-value is created as a new column.
My dataframe is

```
structure(list(region = c("region 1", "region 1", "region 1", 
"region 2", "region 2", "region 2", "region 3", "region 3", "region 3", 
"region 4", "region 4", "region 4", "region 5", "region 5", "region 5", 
"region 6", "region 6", "region 6"), group = c("Male", "Female", 
"p-value", "Male", "Female", "p-value", "Male", "Female", "p-value", 
"Male", "Female", "p-value", "Male", "Female", "p-value", "Male", 
"Female", "p-value"), value = c(1.1, 0.9, 0.001, 0.5, 1.2, 0.612, 
0.9, 0.1, 0.001, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 1.3, 0.8, 0.04, 2.3, 1.5, 0.561
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```

and the desired dataframe is

```
structure(list(region = c("region 1", "region 1", "region 2", 
"region 2", "region 3", "region 3", "region 4", "region 4", "region 5", 
"region 5", "region 6", "region 6"), group = c("Male", "Female", 
"Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", 
"Female", "Male", "Female"), value = c(1.1, 0.9, 0.5, 1.2, 0.9, 
0.1, 0.9, 0.8, 1.3, 0.8, 2.3, 1.5), `p-value` = c(0.001, 0.001, 
0.612, 0.612, 0.001, 0.001, 0.7, 0.7, 0.04, 0.04, 0.561, 0.561
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? If you like to hard-code (error-prone) it: `x = rep(unlist(old[old$group == "p-value", "value"]), each = 2); old = old[!old$group == "p-value", ]; old$pvalue = x`, where `old` is the original data frame. Otherwise, you need to dive into the famous reshaping routines (`base::reshpae`, `tidyr::pivot_wider`, ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the OP has tagged only `dplyr` and not `tidyr`, the simple strategy to `mutate` a new column will also work in this case

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(p_value = value[group == 'p-value'], .by = region) %>% 
  filter(group != 'p-value')
#> # A tibble: 12 × 4
#>    region   group  value p_value
#>    <chr>    <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 region 1 Male     1.1   0.001
#>  2 region 1 Female   0.9   0.001
#>  3 region 2 Male     0.5   0.612
#>  4 region 2 Female   1.2   0.612
#>  5 region 3 Male     0.9   0.001
#>  6 region 3 Female   0.1   0.001
#>  7 region 4 Male     0.9   0.7  
#>  8 region 4 Female   0.8   0.7  
#>  9 region 5 Male     1.3   0.04 
#> 10 region 5 Female   0.8   0.04 
#> 11 region 6 Male     2.3   0.561
#> 12 region 6 Female   1.5   0.561
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much for taking time and providing a solution to my question

Comment: I am using ```tbl_svysummary``` which returns < 0.001 as one of the p-values. I notice that your proposed solution converts such cases to NA. By any chance do you have a work around? Thanks!

Comment: @StephenOkiya, That should not be.  May be some other reason.

Comment: You are right - there was ```as.numeric()``` function that was doing that

Answer (score 2):

Your `group` columns contains both gender and p-value. You want to  keep gender and put the p-value in its own column. So this will take two operations. You can use `tidyr` for both. First [`pivot_wider()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html) the `group` column, then [`pivot_longer()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html) all columns except `group` and `` `p-value` ``.

```r
dat |>
    tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = group) |>
    tidyr::pivot_longer(
        !c(region, `p-value`),
        names_to = "group"
    ) |>
    # These last two steps are get the same row and column order
    dplyr::relocate(
        region, group, value, `p-value`
    ) |>
    dplyr::arrange(region, desc(group))

# # A tibble: 12 × 4
#    region   group  value `p-value`
#    <chr>    <chr>  <dbl>     <dbl>
#  1 region 1 Male     1.1     0.001
#  2 region 1 Female   0.9     0.001
#  3 region 2 Male     0.5     0.612
#  4 region 2 Female   1.2     0.612
#  5 region 3 Male     0.9     0.001
#  6 region 3 Female   0.1     0.001
#  7 region 4 Male     0.9     0.7  
#  8 region 4 Female   0.8     0.7  
#  9 region 5 Male     1.3     0.04 
# 10 region 5 Female   0.8     0.04 
# 11 region 6 Male     2.3     0.561
# 12 region 6 Female   1.5     0.561
```

The last two `dplyr` steps are to get the column and row order the same as your expected output. If this is not necessary you can skip them.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking time and providing a solution to my question